# передача bit(32) в хранимую функцию на С PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

Пишу хранимую функцию на языку С для PostgreSQL.
Встретился с проблемой передачи bit(32) в качестве параметра. Точнее передать нет никакой проблемы, а вот как правильно считать для меня остается загадкой.
Передавать нужно именно bit(32). Заранее спасибо за любые мысли!

Comment: Скорее всего это `unsigned int`, попробуйте так.

Comment: судя по всему — это один тип с `VarBit`.. см. комментарии в `<utls/varbit.h>`